# Prevent unauthorized network connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, security, windows-firewall

Can another computer (connected to Network B) gain access to my computer (connected to Network A through wifi) via any means? How can I protect myself from such unauthorized connections? I have the standard Windows XP firewall and free version of AVG.

Comment: What are the IP addresses and subnet-masks of the both network?

Comment: Start by replacing Windows XP and go from there. That is the biggest security flaw you have in that setup.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if,

- Knows the wireless password
- Have access to the main router (IF both networks connected to one router)
- Have a knowledge on pirating wireless networks
- Have an access to any computer that is connected to the network

How to protect your network ?
Simply, have a strong WiFi network password, and protect your PC with some of good security programs, update your security program, and windows updates, and do a virus scan to your PC regularly.

I Think this should be enough,